# The label in Django Forms doesn't change its name

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I am trying to change my label in Forms. But despite trying, I can't get a label change for `consumer` field. I also don't see a typo made by me.

**models.py**

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Klient')
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Sprzedawca')
    vat = models.ForeignKey(Vat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Stawka VAT')
    annual_usage_kw = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Roczne zużycie KW')
    monthly_usage_kwh = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Miesięczne zużycie KWH')
    monthly_usage_zl = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Miesieczne zużycie PLN')
    excepted_power = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Oczekiwana moc KW')
    roof_orientation = models.ForeignKey(RoofConstruction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Konstrukcja dachu')
    price_per_kw = models.ForeignKey(PricePerKw, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Cena za KW')
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, verbose_name='Produkt')
    inverter = models.ManyToManyField(Inverter, blank=True, verbose_name='Inverter')
    number_of_product = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Liczba produktów (opcjonalnie)')
    employer_margin_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Marża cenowa pracownika')
    accessories = models.ManyToManyField(Accesorie, blank=True, verbose_name='Akcesoria')
```

**forms.py**

```
class OfferParametersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ('customer', 'vat', 'annual_usage_kw', 'monthly_usage_kwh', 'monthly_usage_zl', 'excepted_power',
                  'roof_orientation', 'price_per_kw')
        labels = {'customer': 'Klient',
                  'vat': 'VAT',
                  'annual_usage_kw': 'Roczne zużycie KW',
                  'monthly_usage_kwh': 'Miesięczne zużycie KWH',
                  'monthly_usage_zl': 'Miesieczne zużycie PLN',
                  'excepted_power': 'Oczekiwana moc KW',
                  'roof_orientation': 'Konstrukcja dachu',
                  'price_per_kw': 'Cena za KW',
                  }
```

[image]

I use my form as method `{{ form.as_p }}`. I guess I might be making some stupid mistakes. But I don't see the wrong setting and my label is still `costumer` instead of `klient`. How to change costumer label to `klient`.

**views.py**

```
def parameters(request):
    #basic
    step = 2
    step_percentages = 33
    template_name = 'Nowa oferta'
    object_id = request.session.get('costumer_id')
    #form
    OfferParametersForm.base_fields['customer'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Customer.objects.filter(owner=request.user))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OfferParametersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
            qd.update(customer=cd['customer'], vat=cd['vat'], annual_usage_kw=cd['annual_usage_kw'],
                      monthly_usage_kwh=cd['monthly_usage_kwh'], monthly_usage_zl=cd['monthly_usage_zl'],
                      excepted_power=cd['excepted_power'], roof_orientation=cd['roof_orientation'],
                      price_per_kw=cd['price_per_kw'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                '{}?{}'.format(reverse('app:products'), qd.urlencode())
            )
    else:
        form = OfferParametersForm(initial={'customer': object_id,
                                            'vat': 1})
context = {'step': step,
           'step_percentages': step_percentages,
           'template_name': template_name,
           'form': form}
return render(request, 'app/parameters.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you show your view where you instantiate your form and render your template ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. I show my views.py above.

Comment: Can you explain what this line do : `OfferParametersForm.base_fields['customer'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Customer.objects.filter(owner=request.user))`

Comment: I don't see how this would affect the form label but in your parameters() method in views you use "costumer" instead of "customer" in object_id = request.session.get('costumer_id'). And you have some more typos ("costumer", "consumer") in your question here. I would try to check for some typos in your code once more.